# HP Mini 110 Pant Temp 4 Celcius (39 F)

Tags: windows-7, temperature, lm-sensors

Under the motherboard temperature, pant isnt returning a value that seems normal. Why is that? I am in a room that is about 75 F.

On linux, with lm-sensors there is only a THRM reading and a core readint.

[image]

Comment: Motherboard temperatures are often implemented in not-quite-standard ways. Using generic tools to read and guess at the answers often provides faulty readings. (esp. for sensors which are not connected but for which there are registers. Though those often read -127 or similar values).

Comment: Could it be a faulty sensor? Or is it most likely a faulty reading?

Comment: Faullt sensor. Not connected sensor. Wrong interpretation (e.g. reading a temp value from what is a control register). Any of those can cause this.  Did HP supply a tool to read these temperatures?

Comment: HP didnt supply a tool. When I boot up into linux tho, this sensor doesn't show up with lm-sensors (only core and acpi thrm). Also using speedfan I only get the cpu core temp, acpi THRM, and the hdd smart temp. So I would assume HWMonitor was looking at a control register as Pant doesnt seem like the name for a temperature sensor either.